Problema al instalar WSL en windows
Quiero instalar WSL en mi PC windows, al intentar WSL --install me sale el mensaje en la imagen:

Para instalarlo estoy haciendo los pasos del siguiente enlace https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/install-manual
alli me indica que coloque dos codigos en el powershell
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
el primero lo ejecuta sin problemas pero el segundo me genera un error (Error: 0x800f080c el nombre de caracteristica VirtualMachinePlatform es desconocido) como se ve en la imagen:

Alguien me puede ayudar en porque me sale ese error? Gracias de antemano.

Trata con wsl --install que te aparece como sugerencia, puede ser que funcione.

No me funciona, fue lo que intente primero :s en la primera imagen sale el error que me genera, me sale "el termino wsl no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, funcion, archivo de script o programa ejecutable"

Tienes etiquetas windows y ubuntu. En la pregunta mencionas Windows, en realidad para qué sistema operativo quieres una solución?

En este sitio web hay una solución:

https://webinstall.dev/wsl/

Hay un comando que requiere curl:

https://curl.se/windows/

Desde el cmd abrir con permisos de administrador:
curl -sS https://webi.sh/wsl | sh

